# Getting Just the ValueMember from ComboBox

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, combobox

I have a combobox with I am filling like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Later I am attempting to get the value like this:

```
string value = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I am expecting a string which contains "DFT". What I am getting, however is a string that contains "{ Item = Default Project, Value = DFT }".

Any idea how I can get just the DFT out of there?

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot that it wasn't apparent. Items is a List generated from an XDocument (Linq) using the descendants method. The XML looks like:

```
<Parent>
  <Item>
    <Name>Default project</Name>
    <Value>DFT</Value>
  </Item>
</Parent>
```

EDIT 2: This is my best guess as to the method I used to generate list (its at work and I don't remember it fully):

```
var items = (from i in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
                     select new { Item = i.Element("Name").Value, Value = i.Element("Value").Value }).ToList();
```

Comment: That should work, are you sure `Value` member (of your item) is type of string?

Comment: Show us what items is

Comment: If items is a Collection<class>, what you're doing should work, under the presumption that there is a property named 'Item' and a property named 'Value'.  If, however, 'item' is the class name, and the display member you had in mind is called 'ItemName' and the intended value member is 'ItemId', this won't go anywhere.

Comment: Original post updated. Sorry about that. Of course, the lamda expression used to populate list is now at work so I cannot post it until tomorrow.

Comment: I know there is probably a much better way, but for the interim I solved this with regex: var match = Regex.Match(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), "(Value = )(.*)( })");